# When should you increase stack size ( Visual Studio C++ )

Tags: c++

When should we increase the stack size for a C++ program?

Why isn't it unlimited and are there any reasons for not increasing the stack size?

And does a program crash if the stack is full?

And also can we increase the stack size for a particular thread?

Comment: Well, it obviously can't be unlimited because your computer has a limited amount of memory.

Comment: ***Why*** do you think you need to increase the stack size? What is the problem you're having? Normally (in 99.999999% of all cases) you should never have to do that. If you have problems, it's more likely it can be solved by fixing your code instead.

Comment: A program usually is not only one thread. It might be hundreds of threads in some cases. Hundreds of threads times dozen processes times gigabytes won't work on many machines. Also, the idea of stack is _locality_, cache friendly storage. If you need more mem, you can always resort to allocate on heap and pass a ptr on stack.

Comment: @0x5453 **actually**, on linux you can run `$ ulimit -s unlimited` :p   -- all jokes aside, I really hope someone answers this.

Comment: What's the reason for asking such a question? This sounds like a homework assignment in an introductory chapter or session from a class or a textbook on operating system design and implementation; and the question is expected to be answered based on the material that's just been learned or described in the chapter.

Comment: An exhausted stack (compared to what was preset) often is a sign for something going wrong in the code, e.g. infinite recursion. If you create large automatic (scope local) variables, you can increase the stack size with a linker flag. You can also allocate large data from the heap instead.

Comment: Well, my conclusions can be discredited at any time, simply by offering a more likely explanation.

Comment: How to do increase stack depends on operating system and compiler. There's no single and simple solution that works everywhere.

Comment: You should increase the stack size, to avoid a stack overflow ;o)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with learning, I happen to be learning too, right at this instant. Learning is a good thing. But I find that back when I was learning in a class setting, my learning was much more effective when I kept careful notes and reviewed them before attempting to do my homework.

Comment: `I mean why is there a limit of some megabytes?` many MCUs don't even have that much stack and just have a hardware stack of 8-32 levels deep. Most of the time you use only a few tens of stackframes and hence doesn't even consumed 1MB (which is the default stack size on Windows). If you want "unlimited" stack then use golang which will automatically resize the stack as needed with the obvious trade off by the slowdown to check stack size before each function

Answer (score 3):

> When should we increase the stack size for a C++ program?

When you have a specific program or a use case that overflows the stack. Note that the ideal solution is to modify the program or algorithm to behave within reasonable stack size, but that isn't always possible in practice (e.g. you have a program you cannot modify).

> Why isn't it unlimited and are there any reasons for not increasing the stack size?

Because is not possible within the current architecture. In the virtual memory space of a program there are multiple stacks, one for each thread so specific limited space must be reserved for each stack. Keep in mind that a stack cannot be fragmented and cannot move (relative to the virtual memory space).

> And does a program crash if the stack is full?

*Please forgive my pedantic note:* If the stack is full but you don't exceed it there is not problem. The problem is when the program overflows the stack.

I am not sure exactly. I think there is OS level protection against stack overflow in which case the program crashes with stack overflow exception. If am wrong and there is no protection (or if there is a setting to disable it) it depends on what it is in the memory you overflow. In any case, nothing good happens.

> Why is the stack size set so small by default?

*ok, it's not your question, but I feel it ties in here neatly*

It's not. The OSes need to find a balance between too big of a stack and too small. Too big and you cut into the heap memory, too small and you make programs overflow it.

What can reside on the stack: call frames and local variables allocated on the stack. Call frames are very small (they usually contain just 1 pointer per frame) and local variables usually are pretty small. Big objects go on the heap.

What can overflow a stack? The most likely culprit is recursion. A recursive algorithm can easily overflow the stack with a big maximum recursion depth. But every recursive algorithm can be rewritten. Either there is an equivalent iterative algorithm or simply use a stack on the heap instead. That is the reason why in stack based memory allocation languages like C and C++ in the real world recursive algorithms with unbound recursion depths are avoided.